# how to get secured files from restful web service

Tags: php, rest

I am designing a RESTful web service and i a bit confused about how to serve the files on the API endpoint. these files is confidence for a certain users only.

I am using AWS S3 sign approach to signing all requests to the API. The current scenario is that i have a list shows all files that belongs to the current logged-in user. i didn't want anyone that hits a url of any file to show the content of this file. I need to use the same encryption approach i used for the rest of controllers with the files, so all files have to be secured with Authorization header sent with every get request.

So, What is the best approach to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your application should check what user is trying to access what file and if the user does not match the owner of the file you should return a 403 status (Forbidden). It sounds like you already know if a user is an owner of the file given that you list only files belonging to a user. Just refuse to return the file if the user is not the owner.

Comment: the problem isn't in the page itself or in the returned files to the user. I could return the proper files to every user, but what i am searching for is how to prevent anyone to use this file just by type the url in the address bar. also i don't know the ideal approach that i have to use in order to such situation

Comment: You can control who is allowed to download a file. If a user is allowed to down load a file you return the file. If the user isn't allowed you return an error (403). To do this you check which user is trying to access a file on each and ever request for a file. You already do this for the lists of files. Just add the same logic to do it for each individual file.

Comment: Do i have to use the same mechanism used on every request by signing the request with authorization header to prevent anonymous calls to the API then if someone trying to access a file outside my clients i would return an error (403) because he didn't provide the proper signature. right ?

Comment: Yes. Every request should be considered independently. If a user makes a 100 individual requests for 100 different files you should check each and every request individually to see if the user is allowed download the file. REST is stateless, the server shouldn't guess who the user is based on the previous requests, it should authenticate the user on every request.

Comment: So, for such a situation if i am trying to show an individual picture for the current logged in user. and i am using backbonejs to build my client and in an normal case i would write the following code `<img src="path/to/image" />` but here i need to sign the request in order to get the file from the endpoint, Do i have to create this procedure in the wrapper controller that save the secret key of the client and path it to the backbone, i am a bit confused :D

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about Backbone.js, so I can't help with how to implement this in Backbone. I'm guessing it will be very similar to how you do it for the list of user files, since the server must know who the user is in order to give them a list of their files.